# How to access Node JS route Url in Angular JS site

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working on a site which is in Angular JS language. Now for website, I have to generate dynamic sitemaps and for this I used Node JS and created a **xml.js** route in node and wrote hello world.

Now the problem is, I am not able to use access this xml.js in angular site. Here is **xml.js** code :

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/test", function() {
    console.log("hello world");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is **server.js** code :

```
var express=require('express');
var xml = require("./xml");
var app=express();
app.use('/xml',xml);
app.use('/',express.static('app'));
app.listen(9000) ;
```

Now whenever I try to access http://192.168.0.19:9000/xml/test I am being redirected to home page always.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.This code work for me

You need to pass req and res parameter.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('home page')
})
router.get("/test", function (req, res) {
    console.log("hello world");
    res.send('test page')
})
```